# How to switch to frame by class name in Selenide?

Tags: selenide

How to switch to frame by class name in Selenide?

This doesn't work

```
switchTo().frame(".demo-frame");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need to do this:

```
      switchTo().frame($(".selector"));
```

Or the more readable version:

```
SelenideElement selector = $(By.cssSelector(".click-me-senpai"));
switchTo().frame(selector);
```

The `frame()` method accepts a WebElement, or a provided name/id (specifically `name` or `id` attributes in the DOM)